# How to add Done Button to dismiss the Number Pad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uitextfield

I followed the tutorial:
http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

to dismiss the number pad,
this tutorial add the button as sub view to the number pad,

my problem is, in the same view I am using the text field to enter text also,so, how to differentiate the number field, and text field. so that I can hide the button view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can use UITextFieldDelegate Protocol instead of NSNotifications, and inside methods `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` check which field is being used. Something like this:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
if (textField == self.passwordField) {
  // add subview...
}
```

Comment: This method not getting called, i have used UITextFieldDelegate protocol. can u tell the reasons,

Comment: It should be called. Please make sure that you've connected text field's delegate outlet to the view controller in Interface Builder.